# Python Database that stays with the program

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, mysql-python

So mysql works great when you log into  your mysql database program on that device but what if you want to move the program to another device, the connected databases wont work...

Is there anyway to have the database somehow within the python file, so that when I move it to other devices it will act the same...Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to store some simple information, Sqlite3 does exact what you're looking for. This is a sql database that is entirely run on a file on the hardrive that the application is running from.

But be careful what you put in this database. This is not meant to be a high performance database, and will crumble if you stress it too much.

Comment: So on new devices I would need to recreate the database, and would the database be it's own file or part of the .py file?

Comment: It will be it's own file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a database external to the host.  You can then use DNS or an ip address to access the mysql database as long as the new device has connectivity to the database.  For mobile apps and mobile devices, build out an API on top of the data that you'd like to be able to access and then secure the API with appropriate credentials.

Comment: I will definitely look into that! very helpful, thank you!